# Complete and unabridged proof of the theorem of acyclic models

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Can someone indicate me where I can find a complete and unabridged proof of the said theorem? By "complete and unabridged" I mean not writing something like "details are left to the reader as an exercise."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at

Barr, M. *Acyclic models*, CRM Monograph Series, Volume 17.
 American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI (2002),

and see if that satisfies you for completeness.

A theorem involving **crossed complexes** rather than **chain complexes** is in Section 10.4 of the book partially titled [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html) (2011).  This version gives in some instances homotopy equivalences  rather than just homology equivalences.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation, Professor Brown.  Yes I will have a look at both books. (BTW, you are generous to have made your books available free online.  I am really impressed.)

Comment: It's unfortunate that Barr wrote a book *and* an article with the exact same title -- I've never been able to find that book online...

Comment: Re free online: actually T&G is available at £5 from kagi.com, but I am aware of free downloadable versions. The main thing is I want people to read the books. The big EMS book is available on my web site courtesy of the contract with the EMS.I hope readers will also insist that both books are available in print in their institution's library! Books are a good random access device, and more readable, though non clickable, but can be heavy to carry around.

Comment: I received "Acyclic Models" today from Amazon and had a look at it. I think it is written in the same spirit as your "Topology and Groupoids" and "Nonabelian Algebraic Topology," that is, to explain the subject thoroughly *ab initio.*  Thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the following paper:

> Samuel Eilenberg and Saunders MacLane. “Acyclic models”. In: *Amer. J. Math.* 75
>   (1953), pp. 189–199. ISSN: 0002-9327. JSTOR: [2372628](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372628).

I read it a few months ago so I may not remember perfectly, but if I recall correctly, everything was done in detail and I didn't have to fill in any significant gap. The most difficult thing was adapting the notations (I had to keep a cheat sheet while reading the paper).

Comment: It's amazing to learn that the original article is accessible. Thank you for the enlightenment. Yes, I will have a look at it.